# Regex to parse script tags excluding script tags inside js

Tags: regex

Need regular expression to correctly parse script tags. I tried to use 
`/<script([^>]*)>(.*)<\/script>/iUsg`, but it matches script tags inside strings inside script tag. Please help!

Sample code i need to match:

```
<html>
<script>

    var = '<script></script><div>'

</script>

<div>423434</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var b = "<script type='javascript.1.1'></script>";
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use an HTML parsing library?

Comment: Because dom document php library stacks on same problem. It think that there are real tags in javascript strings and brokes html. I trying to escape tags with regex before dom document library will be used.

Comment: Can you clarify what output do you expect after regexp? `var = '<script></script><div>'` and `var b = "<script type='javascript.1.1'></script>";` as script internals?

Comment: Are you trying to get the text between two script tags or the arguments of the script tag?

Comment: You're going to have trouble with this in any case since RegEx does not supprt variable-length lookbehind.  You can only match fixed-length alternatives.

Comment: http://regex101.com/r/hM2zT2/2 result here

Comment: What should be your correct result? The internal blocks?

Comment: i need to catch all between script tags but closing script tag inside js must be excluded

Comment: resolved by html cleaner library...